# Custom Attributes from GeoJSON files not loading through ogr2ogr to PostGIS database

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, postgis-2.3

I am ingesting hundreds of GeoJSON files which I need to load in the PostGIS database. I am using ogr2ogr in a shell script to automate the process on a daily basis using the below command.

`ogr2ogr -update -append -f "PostGreSQL" PG:"dbname=xyz user=postgres" <file-name> -nln <table-name>`

My sample GeoJSON file is as follows:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features":[{
      "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [[0.0,0.5], [1.0,1.5]]
       },
       "properties":{
            "cam-id": "iir",
            "file-name": "iir_20092021.json"
       }
}]    
}
```

I want to store cam-id and file-name also in database which is happening for the first file but subsequently, the database shows empty values for these columns when I ingest more files. The geometry column is getting added though.

Comment: It is a violation of best security practice to load user data as the `postgres` login. Instead use `postgres` to create login(s), group(s), user(s) and schema(s) to manage data.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is invalid as GeoJSON as you can test in https://geojsonlint.com.

`Line 3: GeoJSON features must have a type=feature member`

With this fix I suppose it will work for you.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features":[{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [[0.0,0.5], [1.0,1.5]]
       },
       "properties":{
            "cam-id": "iir",
            "file-name": "iir_20092021.json"
       }
}]    
}
```

Test with the edited json file:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=db user=user password=pw" fixed.json -nln appendtest2
```

Result shown with pgAdmin

[image]

**EDIT**

The screen capture reveals what goes wrong when adding attributes "cam-id" and "file-name". When the table was created the field names were automatically changed into `cam_id` and `file_name`. This is documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html

> LAUNDER: This may be “YES” to force new fields created on this layer
> to have their field names “laundered” into a form more compatible with
> PostgreSQL. This converts to lower case and converts some special
> characters like “-” and “#” to “_”. If “NO” exact names are preserved.
> The default value is “YES”. If enabled the table (layer) name will
> also be laundered.

Running the command with debug option

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -f "PostGreSQL" PG:"dbname=mydb user=postgres" test.json -nln test_table --debug on
```

prints the error

```
GDALVectorTranslate: Skipping field 'cam-id' not found in destination layer 'test_table'.
GDALVectorTranslate: Skipping field 'file-name' not found in destination layer 'test_table'.
```

Select what to do:

1. Run the commands with `-lco LAUNDER=NO`
2. Change the attribute names

Having minus sign in the table name in PostGIS makes it a bit more tedious to white SQL queries later. You must write "file-name", because without double quotes the meaning will be "file" minus "name".

Comment: Hi, Thanks for pointing out. Even after adding `type=feature` also, I am not seeing values in non-geographic custom database columns .

Comment: Works for me as you can see from the edited answer.

Comment: Hi, As I have posted in the question, it works for me also but only first time. When I ingest a second file, the column values appear empty. I am using the command `ogr2ogr -update -append -f "PostGreSQL" PG:"dbname=mydb user=postgres" test.json -nln test_table`

Comment: Ok, this was a funny case. See the edited answer. We lost time because there was both invalid JSON and sub-optimal attribute names involved. But you will certainly remember `--debug on` now. It is documented but not in a very visible place https://gdal.org/programs/vector_common_options.html.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for rescuing me. It is working with both the options. As due to specifying `lco LAUNDER=NO` option, the column-names also have the hyphen, so while querying the database, we need to specify column names within double quotes for the psql prompt to return the relations. So, I have chosen to go with the second option of changing the attribute names in the geojson file itself (using _ instead of -) for easy querying. Really, I will always be remembering `--debug on`.